# Running .exe files (absolute newbie question, sorry)

Tags: virtualbox, wine, virtualization, office365

I have an old computer and decided to play with it. No IT background, just user experience.

I am using computer -extensively- (10+ hours every day).

I dedided to try Linux - Ubuntu (as a newbie friendly version of Linux).

However I struggle to launch crucial software, which is Office 365, UiPath robotic process automation software, Teachmaster vocabulary software, local accounting software from my country among others.

This is a serious issue for me and I dont believe Ubuntu hasnt solved it over the years. I googled a lot and after two days decided to ask here, because Ive found some workarounds like using LibreOffice instead of 365 (but I dont want to switch because of many reasons), I run process automation in UiPath daily, same with accounting soft.

Is there any way how to run those programs? I dont consider Wine (they dont support my soft) or VirtualBox an option (whats the point of switching to Ubuntu if I need to run Windows all the day inside it?)

Please help, because I could not find anything reasonable on the web and I just simply cannot believe that Ubuntu is unable to run omnipresent .exe format.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Exe files are for Windows only. You can run some of them using wine. You mentioned alternatives already: use linux software, or Windows in virtualbox.

Comment: Hi Pilot6, thank you for the answer. So if I understand correctly in order to use my accounting software (for example) I have to run Windows in the virtualbox all day? But what is the point of Ubuntu then if you cannot run any program on it? :-(

Comment: Where does you assumption, that Unix/Linux should be able to run Windows Software, come from? If, in your oppinion, the fact that Unix/Linux can not run Windows software is unbelievable an unreasonable, then why are you using Linux? If you rely on software written for windows, then you best bet would be a Microsoft OS.

Comment: Hi @StrabagISS_Krall it comes from the fact, that I was unaware that .exe is Windows only. This week is really my first experience with other desktop OS than Windows. Sorry for newbie question and unawareness.

Comment: *I just simply cannot believe that Ubuntu is unable to run omnipresent .exe format* Neither is macOS, AFAIK. Some of your software could exist for macOS but it would be in a form usable on OSX, not as .EXE.

Comment: _I just simply cannot believe that Ubuntu is unable to run omnipresent .exe format_  Ubuntu is a version of Linux, and Linux is designed as 'Open Source' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software. EXE is a file format for Windows, and Windows is Closed Source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software ; Microsoft does not provide its source code to Linux developers, which would be required for Linux to infallibly run .EXE apps. In short, blame Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

To get a .exe under Linux running, try Wine. If wine won't work, use a virtualization (preferred VirtualBox). As you don't want use these solution, my suggestion is to leave the 'old world'. Search for replacements.

- crucial software

What did this software do? Just set a few parameters for your hard drive in a not transparent, proprietary way.
Try f.ex. `hdparm` as replacement and learn how hard drives works. Then you don't have to struggle, If you'll switch to another vendor some time.

- Office 365

This is a hard One. LibreOffice/OpenOffice will work for simple tasks. But if you are using Excel for real, it is itchy. Some tasks can be done with the online Version (https://portal.office.com). On the bright side, MS is developing a Teams Client for Linux, I think the Office will follow soon.

- UiPath robotic process automation software

It is an enterprise solution. Most automation should be more or less easy replaceable by python/perl/bash/... But this is an own topic to discuss. If you need it for work: Your company should provide you a system.

- Teachmaster vocabulary software

There are some vocabulary trainers available. Take a look at projects like [Debian Edu](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianEdu), [Edubuntu](https://www.edubuntu.org/), ...

- local accounting software from my country

Is there a Cloud Version?

- among others.

... Just search for alternatives. Sometimes they are better.
Winamp -> Audacious
irfanview/acdsee -> geeqie
icq/aol/msn/... -> pidgin
Adobe Photoshop -> GIMP/Inkscape (only for amateur use)
and so on.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I am not interested to switch from Office 365, seriously its the best tool out there. Tried web version, but it is unable to open files over 5mb in size - so massive pivot table files will not be opened at all. Libre/Open office is a joke comparing to 365 :( But I am installing VirtualBox at the moment and I will try to use Win inside Linux just to try and learn - but I dont think I will stick to such solution.